# Mocking $state change in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Main module being injected with everything;

```
require('./dashboard');
module.exports = angular.module('college', ['college.dashboard'])

    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('college.list', {
                url: '/college',
                templateUrl: '/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                authenticate: true
            });
    })
    .factory('ProjectFactory', require('./services/college.service'));
```

College Index, which makes the dashboard controller available;

```
module.exports = angular.module('college.dashboard', 
  [])
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', require('./dashboard.controller.js'));
```

The college controller exposes the following method;

```
    module.exports = function($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

         $scope.openCollege = function(id) {       
            $rootScope.currentCollege = id;
            $state.go('college.main', {currentCollege: id});
        };
   };
```

The following error is thrown when the unit test calls

```
scope.openCollege (2);
```

Error:

```
 Error: Could not resolve 'college.main' from state ''
```

Creating state;

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        location = $location;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        $rootScope.currentCollege = {};// Empty by default
        state = $state;            

        $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $state: state,
            $location: location
        });

    }));
```

Some of the spec test code;

```
 expect(state.current.name).to.equal('');
 scope.openCollege(2);
```

I need to figure out how to handle/mock *$state.go* during the Karma unit testing so that state knows about college.main.

Any help is appreciated.

J

Comment: Can you share the rest of your test code? Have you injected _$state_ into your test module?

Comment: Added some of the beforeEach logic. This is the very last test that I need to get to pass...all other tests are passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I got it working;

I added the following to the spec test;

```
// Globally defined
var stateSpy;

// within the beforeEach
stateSpy = sinon.stub($state, 'go');

// In the unit test
scope.openCollege (2);
assert(stateSpy.withArgs('college.main', '{currentCollege: 2}').calledOnce);
```

Note: the *$state* was not passed to the the controller.

I now have green tests!

Thanks for your help, gave me the idea of how to make this work.

J

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
it('should be able to go to person edit state', function () {
    DashboardCtrl();
    scope.openProject('12345');
    scope.$digest();
    expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('college.main', { id : '12345' });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that calling the method openCollege(2) returns the error 'Could not resolve 'college.main''. This state is being set by another module which is outside of the these modules. I just need to mock it.

Comment: Did you try spyOn(state, 'go') in your beforeEach? This works fine for me

Comment: spyOn(state, 'go') helped... Thanks